# Pdo count multiple tables at once

Tags: mysql, pdo, count

Is there a way to count multiple tables at with one query:

```
table 1 => 174 rows // $x
table 2 => 3824 rows // $y
table 3 => 295 rows //$z
```

And then use then echo out those counts:

```
echo 'Table one has ' . $x . ' rows';
echo 'Table two has ' . $y . ' rows';
echo 'Table three has ' . $z . ' rows';
```

If there is a way can you help me understand how it works?

Thank you!:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a UNION:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS name, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 'table2', COUNT(*) FROM table2
UNION
SELECT 'table3', COUNT(*) FROM table3
```

Output

```
name     rows
table1   174
table2   3824
table3   295
```

Comment: Hey @Nick, thank you so much for this query. One question tho: i'm fetching data as `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and the output of the above query `json_encode`ed is: `[{"name":"28","rows":"20"},{"name":"17","rows":"38"},{"name":"1","rows":"1"}]` - in other words the counting is ok but can i change the 'name' with 'table-name'?(the first value - 28,17,1 - is the lowest id in each table)

Comment: Hi emma, that is really weird. This query works fine on my MySQL server. Can you show me the exact code you're using?

Comment: Yes @Nick :D after a little bit of testing now the json looks like this: `[{"count":"user_id","rows":"20"},{"count":"city_id","rows":"38"},{"count":"friend_id","rows":"1"}]` - which is ok but still trying to replace `count` with the table name. Here is my current code(i'm just learning on it so i'm sorry if it is not too well indentedX_X: (i will leave it down below in another comment because it is too long to paste it here):

Comment: `$test = $db->prepare("
  SELECT 'user_id' AS count, COUNT(*) AS rows FROM users
  UNION
  SELECT 'city_id', COUNT(*) FROM cities
  UNION
  SELECT 'friend_id', COUNT(*) FROM friends"
 );
 $test->execute();
 echo json_encode($test->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` (this is my current code)

Comment: Oh @Nick, aaaammmm wait a second! I'm pretty dumby :D, it works - i just, on autopilot, replaced the tablename with the column name after `SELECT` X_X. Sorry! Thank you so much for your time and help <3